# Retrieving <title> of a page with URL in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get `<title>` of the urls without using third party packages. Is it possible to get the title of a page from the url without using third party packages.

Routes can be  single or multiple
/I/want/title/?address=http://yahoo.com
/I/want/title/?address=google.com&address=www.dawn.com/events/

app.js

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const app = require('express')();

app.get('/I/want/title/', (req, res, next) => {
  const urls = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
  const queryObject = url.parse('https://nodejs.org/en/', true).query;
  res.send('Sucess');
  next(); // Allows the request to continue to the next middleware in line
});

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Man your code is a mess... Can you post an example of some source data and expected result?

Comment: By "title" are you referring to the value in the html `<title>` element?

Comment: @ΔO 'deltazero'
My route will be like       I/want/title/?address=google.com
and It will parse out the <title></title> tags, render them in html and send back the html in response.

Comment: @Gershom Yes, I am refering to the value in the HTML (<title></title>)

Comment: It sounds like you have a clear idea of the steps required. Which step would you specifically like help with? Note: express will have already parsed query params for you; the one you're interested in is available at `req.query.address`.

Comment: @Gershom I need help with fetching the <title> of the urls passed via routes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `fetch` the requested page, parse the code to extract it's `<title>`.

The `url` is just for passing the url :-) Like parsing that 'https://nodejs.org/en/' uses https protocol etc., not for fetching its remote content.

Use something like this.

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch'),
      express = require('express'),
      app = express()

const parseTitle = (body) => {
  let match = body.match(/<title>([^<]*)<\/title>/) // regular expression to parse contents of the <title> tag
  if (!match || typeof match[1] !== 'string')
    throw new Error('Unable to parse the title tag')
  return match[1]
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const { url } = req.query
  if (!url)
    return res.status(400).end('Missing url query parameter')
  
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.text()) // parse response's body as text
    .then(body => parseTitle(body)) // extract <title> from body
    .then(title => res.send(title)) // send the result back
    .catch(e => res.status(500).end(e.message)) // catch possible errors
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Your server will listen on `http://localhost:3000`, just run this thru your browser:

http://localhost:3000/?url=https://google.com gives `Google`

http://localhost:3000/?url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64051968/retrieving-title-of-a-page-with-url-in-nodejs gives `node.js - Retrieving <title> of a page with URL in NodeJS - Stack Overflow`

Comment: Note that webapps that use [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) may have the following title tag format: `<title data-react-helmet="true">some title</title>`. Changing the regex to `<title.*>([^<]*)<\/title>` will capture title tags both with and without attributes.

Comment: Html tags are not necessarily lowercase. Change the regex to     `body.match(new RegExp(/<title>([^<]*)<\/title>/, 'i'));` to ignore Case.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using no 3rd-party libraries (bad idea?? Also... express is a 3rd party library...), you can use the following:

```
const http = require('http');

let app = require('express')();
app.get('/I/want/title', async (req, res, next) => {
  
  try {
      
    // The same "http" module can help us make a request
    let html = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      
      let [ , protocol, host, port, path ] = req.query.address.match(/(http|https):[/][/]([^:/]*)(:[0-9]*)?([/].*)?/) || [];
      if (![ 'http', 'https' ].includes(protocol)) throw new Error('Supplied url is invalid');
      port = port || (protocol === 'http' ? 80 : 443);
            
      let request = require(protocol).request(`${protocol}://${host}`, { port, method: 'GET', path }, response => {
        
        // Collect the http body in `chunks`
        let chunks = [];
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
        
        // Either reject with error, or resolve with full http body
        response.on('error', err => reject(err));
        response.on('end', () => resolve(chunks.join('')));
      
      });
      request.on('error', err => reject(err));
      request.end();
      
    });
    
    // A regex parse is subject to errors, but should do here:
    let [ ,, title=null ] = html.match(/<title( [^>]*)?>(.*)<[/]title>/i) || [];
    if (!title) throw new Error(`Response contained no title`);
    
    res.send(title.split('\n').map(ln => ln.trim()).filter(Boolean).join(' '));
    
  } catch(err) {
    
    res.status(400).send(`Couldn't get title: ${err.stack}`.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));
    
  }
  
  next(); // Allows the request to continue to the next middleware in line
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

I haven't tested this myself but I expect it to work and handle some more obvious edge-cases.

You can see that specifically making the http request is a real headache; you need to handle http and https somewhat separately. This also expects the "address" param to be a fully qualified domain name with protocol, and optional port and path.

You can try running the server and requesting `http://localhost:3000/I/want/title?address=https://stackoverflow.com`; should produce "Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers". You could also try `http://localhost:3000/I/want/title?address=http://chess2.fun`, and you should see "CHESS2".

Comment: Thank You, What if i am using 2 urls, like /I/want/title/?address=google.com&address=www.dawn.com/events/

Comment: Express will generate an array containing all entries under the same query property. What would your desired outcome be for the example request you've given?

Comment: I am expecting out put like this  <li> google.com - "Google" </li>
       <li> www.dawn.com/events/ - "Events - DAWN.COM" </li>

Comment: It's quite straightforward to move from the code I've given to your case, where multiple titles are retrieved and then enclosed in `<li>` elements. If you encounter difficulty doing that on your own I recommend you ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all metadata from specific url with this:

```
npm install url-metadata --save
```

Code:

```
const urlMetadata = require('url-metadata')

urlMetadata('https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-metadata')
.then((metadata) => {
  console.log(metadata)
  // do stuff with the metadata
  return metadata['title']
},
(err) => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Another code:

```
async metadata(){
  const urlMetadata = require('url-metadata')
  try {
    const metadata = await urlMetadata('https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-metadata')
    return {
      status: 200,
      title: (metadata['title'] || metadata['og:title']),
      description: metadata['description'] || metadata['og:description']
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
    return {
      status: 404
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

a simple req.originalUrl will get what you are looking for if I understand your question. The you can you write javascript string functions to get the part you want

```js
app.get('/I/want/title/', (req, res, next) => {

  const url = req.originalUrl;

  res.send('Sucess');
  next(); // Allows the request to continue to the next middleware in line
});
```